# Next post link on a bootstrap button

Tags: php, pagination, links

Seems extremely simple but it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
<a href="<?php next_post_link(); ?>">
<button class="btn btn-default pull-right">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span>
</button></a>
```

So instead of giving me the next page link, the button has 0 link, I actually have a text next to it with title of the next page and a weird link "localhost:8888/site/next-article-title/a href=" The link is good exceped the "a href" at the end which is weird, but anyway the link is not on the button.

Now if I replace my first line href with a simple http://facebook.com, the link will work and will be on the button as I wish. I must be doing something wrong with the integration of the php link.

Any idea ?

Comment: if I put href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" the link works and is on the button as I wish. I'm lost. need some help on this one!

Answer (score 2):

next_post_link() actually creates an anchor tag, not just the URL.

Try something like below to just get the URL:

```
<?php echo get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(false,'',true)); ?>
```

Comment: Works flawlessly. I was stuck on this "simple" thing for the past 3 hours literally so I owe you a big thank you ! Thanks a lot man.